# Make enemy follow you when within a certain distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, move

I have enemies move along a set path (way points) but I want an enemy to follow the player when you are within a certain distance of it but then when out of that distance, the enemy goes back to its way points and continues moving along the path until the player is within a certain distance again. So it keeps doing that.  Below is the code I got for the enemies to move along the way points.

I am using Unity 2d and C#

```
[SerializeField]
Transform[] waypoints; //EnemyWayPoint;

[SerializeField]
float moveSpeed = 3f;
int waypointIndex = 0;

private void Start()
{
    transform.position = waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position;
}


private void Update()
{
    Move();
}

private void Move()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (transform.position == waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position) { 
        waypointIndex += 1;
    }

    if (waypointIndex == waypoints.Length)
        waypointIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the distance between enemy and player using **Vector3.Distance(otherPos,transformPos)**
and made check for distance according to your choice if it's less than **distVal**, then enemy should follow or action performed

```
var distVal=5.0f;
var dis=Vector3.Distance(enemyTransform.position,playerTransform.position);
if(dis<=disVal)
{
  //what enemy should do.
}
```

Next is your own choice for normalization of vectors you set while read for distance document [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html)

Comment: thanks I will try it.  Should I name the player "other" so it knows to follow the player?

Answer (score 0):

Arslan's answer is fine -
just adding a slight change to the code so you know it can be done this way too...

```
var distVal=5.0f;        
if (Vector3.Distance(enemyTransform.position, playerTransform.position) < disVal)
            {
                Debug.Log("Enemy following you");
            }
```

It's much the same but good to know of other ways it exists.